# Mongo DB text search with $elemMatch on other fields

Tags: mongodb, text, mongodb-query

I have a document structure that looks like:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": 1,
      "c": "hello world"
    },
    {
      "b": 2,
      "c": "boom!"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a text index on `a.c` and a normal index on `a.b`

I would like to achieve a query that performs a text search on `a.c` whilst filtering on `a.b`

My equivalent SQL (sorry this is where I am familiar) is:

```
select * from table where a.b = 1 and a.c like 'hello'
```

When I perform the following mongo query on this dataset it doesn't return an expected result.

```
db.inventory.find( { "a": { $elemMatch: { b: 1, c: $text: { search: "hello" } } } } )
```

I'm not really expecting this to work but maybe someone better educated in mongo can shine the light

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$text` operator applies to any values of `a.c` so this ...

```
db.inventory.find({'a.b': 1, $text: { $search: "hello" } })
```

... will match the document you supplied.

However, your proposed usage of `$elemMatch` suggests that you want these two predicates to be applied to each sub document within `a` such that a match is only returned if `a.b = 1` and the **sibling** `a.c` contains "hello".

You cannot use `$text` inside `$elemMatch`, however you can use `$regex` like so:

```
db.inventory.find({ a: { $elemMatch: {'b': 1, 'c': { $regex: /^hello/ }}} })
```

The above command will find documents where at least one sub document of `a` meets **both** of these conditions:

- `a.b = 1`
- `a.c like "hello%"`

If the value for `a.c` is anchored the above command will even use an index. So, if you can rely on an anchored value then you can ceate a non text index on `a.c` and you'll get indexed partial text searches when using `$regex`.

If you really must have a text index (perhaps you cannot rely on the value being anchored or maybe you need stemming functionality) then the search will have to be in two parts, using an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([ 
  { $match : { $text: { $search: "hello" } } },
  { $match : { 'a.b': 1 } } 
])
```

Comment: You are correct about the fact I cannot rely on the values being anchored. My understanding of the above aggregate means that it will first perform the text search and filter documents that match the query "hello" and then perform the "a.b" match on value 1. However this at first doesn't look like it will give me the $elemMatch process which means that a single element in the array matches both a.b = 1 and a.c like 'hello' instead to me it reads like: any document with any item in array a.c like 'hello' and any item in array a.b = 1.

Comment: That's correct. Only `$elemMatch` will guarantee this: << you want these two predicates to be applied to each sub document within a such that a match is only returned if a.b = 1 and the sibling a.c contains "hello" >>. Are indexed searches essential or can you cope with some unindexed `$regex` seaches (i.e. where the caller happens to not supply an anchored vaule)? If unindexed searches are a no-no then you may be forced to consider restructuring your documents to facilitate this use case i.e. move away from the array of sub documents thereby elimniating the need for `$elemMatch`.

Comment: Would a combination of yours and @Alex Blex's work? I can guarantee that the text query provided by a user will be no more complicated than a substring match e.g. "hello wo" should match "hello world", "bonjour and hello world" etc.

If I used the aggregate approach I could first use the full text search to minimize the number of documents matched then perform the second match including a regex which would execute the AND'ing e.g.

`db.inventory.aggregate([
  { $match: { $text: { $search: "hello" } } },
  { $match: { a: { $elemMatch: { b: 1, c: { $regex: "hello" } } } } } 
])`

Comment: That makes sense. It's certainly functional i.e. will give you the correct answer. Re the non functionals ... when aggregating, the `$text` predicate [must be the first stage in the pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#restrictions), the second `$match` would then benefit from the reduced set produced by the text search. So, the cost of a failure to apply the index for the regex (i.e. if the value was not anchored) would be reduced.

Comment: @fungus1487 this "hello wo" thingie. Make sure you understand [how text index works in mongo db](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/). Such search string won't find "hello world" nor "bonjour and hello world".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @glitching's, you still can use $regex with $text together to benefit from fulltext index:

```
db.inventory.find( { 
    "a": { $elemMatch: { 
        b: 1, 
        c: { $regex: "hello" }
    } } 
    $text: { $search: "hello" }
} )
```

Answer (score -1):

To perform text search into MongoDB database a text index needs to be created on fields into which text needs to be searched.

Text index facilitates searching of text across fields belonging to collection of MongoDB database.

According to above description I have created a wildcard text index.

With a wildcard text index, MongoDB indexes every field that contains string data for each document in the collection.

```
db.inventory.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

To perform a text search on a.c along with filtering on a.b,as a solution please try executing following MongoDB find operation into MongoDB shell after creating text index.

```
db.inventory.find({
    $text: {
        $search: 'hello'
    },
    a: {
        $elemMatch: {
            b: 1
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm afraid the use case is where a.c = x and a.b = y using $elemMatch otherwise I will get false positives.